# js flat array to nested by map() and reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have flat array like below and i want to transform it to get nested array with parent-children structure.

```
 let arr = [
  {
   id: 4,
   parentId:1,
   value: 20
  },
   {
   id: 1,
   parentId:2,
   value: 20
  },
   {
   id: 2,
   parentId:1,
   value: 20
  },
   {
   id: 3,
   parentId:1,
   value: 20
  },
   {
   id: 4,
   parentId:2,
   value: 20
  },
 ]
```

I want to transform this array in this way:

```
[
 { id: 1,
   children: [
      { id:4,
        value:20,
        parentId:1
     },
     { id: 2,
       value: 20,
       parentId: 1
    }
...
]
```

How can i achive it  using functions map and reduce? Would be appreciate for any advices)

Comment: is the data sorted? comes the parent before the children? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group the objects based on the `parentId` and use `array#map` to generate an array of id and children.

```js
let data = [ { id: 4, parentId:1, value: 20 }, { id: 1, parentId:2, value: 20 }, { id: 2, parentId:1, value: 20 }, { id: 3, parentId:1, value: 20 }, { id: 4, parentId:2, value: 20 }]

var grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.parentId] = r[o.parentId] || [];
  r[o.parentId].push(o);
  return r;
}, {});
var result = Object.keys(grouped).map(id => ({id, children: grouped[id]}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```